# Cannot convert value of type 'UserInfoEntity!.Type' to expected argument type 'NSEntityDescription'

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

I'm working with core data to save data from my users, I'm following a tutorial with Swift 3 It works perfectly fine on the tutorial and actually the code works on my Xcode too but it does show some errors!
[Here is an image of my code and the errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sIR7.png)

Full error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'UserInfoEntity!.Type' to expected argument type 'NSEntityDescription'

And the the other error:

> Cannot call value of non-function type 'NSEntityDescription?'

[Images of my core data entities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfAEY.jpg)

Ask anything if the info is not complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your line:

```
var newUser = UserInfoEntity(entity: UserInfoEntity!, insertInto: self.appDelegate.coreDataStack.managedObjectContext)
```

With:

```
var newUser = UserInfoEntity(entity: UserEntity!, insertInto: self.appDelegate.coreDataStack.managedObjectContext)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, you're passing "UserInfoEntity" class type instead of an object of that class - the 5th line of code.
Advice: keep your variables in lowercase.